# return each word of a string into a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

i wanted to return every word of a string iinto a node but it didnt work at first now its working but it adds some weird characters automatically idk why if anyone can show me how to fix it please .

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct listeMots{

    char val[20];
    struct listeMots *next;
}listeMots;



listeMots motsDe(char* t);



int main()
{
char* t;
t = "this is a test but it is bugging  ";

  listeMots nchlh;
  nchlh = motsDe(t);  




    return 0;
}


listeMots motsDe(char* t){
 int i=0 ,j=0;
 char* temp;
 
    listeMots *tete = malloc(sizeof(listeMots));
   listeMots *ptr = tete;
   while (t[i] != '\0')
   {
       if('a'<=t[i] && t[i]<='z' ){          
           ptr->val[j] = t[i];
           
           i++;
           j++;
        
       }
       else if (t[i] == ' '){
           j = 0;
           
           printf("%s -->",ptr->val);
           ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(listeMots));
           ptr = ptr->next;
           i++;
       }
       else{
           j= 0;
            printf("%s -->",ptr->val);

           ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(listeMots));
           ptr = ptr->next;
           ptr->val[0] = t[i];
           printf("%s -->",ptr->val);
           ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(listeMots));
           ptr = ptr->next;
       }
   }
return *tete;
}
```

i cant really see where the error is i know that im close but still im kinda lost right now

Comment: `if('a' <= t[i] <= 'z' )`  is correct syntax but doesn't do what you think – C isn't written like a math expression. Please try `if('a' <= t[i] && t[i] <= 'z' )` . Or more simply `if(islower(t[i]))`

Comment: `listeMots *tete ;` You never assign to this. Did you mean `listeMots tete ;` ?

Comment: thank u both u made me notice 2 mistakes now its kinda working but the output is kinda weird , its adding some weird characters i will edit my code and show u how it is

Comment: Make sure you terminate the strings with `\0`.

Comment: did it and it didnt change anything and when i put a character like a " ? or , for example it creats an infinite loop idk why (update fixed the infinite loop problem but idk what to do about the weird characters)

Comment: In the else block where you checked for space, before resetting variable `j`, you should do `ptr->val[j] = '\0'; `, so that words properly get terminated. Also, in your second else block, you are not incrementing variable `i`, need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

things that are wrong with the OPs posted code.

1. regarding: `listeMots motsDe(char* t)`  the function: `motsDe()` returns a pointer, not an instance of the struct, so the signature should be: `listeMots * motsDe(char* t)`
2. the `next` field (on the last struct in the linked list should contain NULL, not what ever trash was in memory.  To fix this, suggest all calls to `malloc()` be replaced with calls to `calloc()` *note there a different parameter list* which will initialize all the fields to '\0'.  As a nice side effect, no more trash characters being printed in the calls to `printf()`
3. Suggest tracking the number of characters in a word to assure that the 20 byte array: `val[]` is not overrun.
4. strongly suggest paying attention to the code indentation.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces
5. the `temp` variable is not used,  Suggest removing that declaration.
6. suggest adding: `#include <ctype.h>`  so you can use functions like `isalpha()`.
7. regarding your question about characters like `?`  Suggest you simply skip over them.
8. regarding statements like: `ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(listeMots));`  For robust code, strongly suggest checking (!=NULL) the returned value (to assure the operation was successful)  When not successful (==NULL) it is good programming practice to output, to `stderr`, an appropriate error message, similar to:  `perror( "malloc for instance of struct listeMots failed" );` followed by free'ing the allocated memory then calling `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are defined in the `stdlib.h` header file.
9. the posted code leaks memory because the allocated memory has not been returned to the OS,  Suggest before exiting, looping through the linked list and passing each of the pointers to allocated memory to the `free()` function.